# Different way to compute arc length of vector function

Tags: linear-algebra

> Compute the length of the arc given by $\textbf{w}(t) = \langle t^2,0,t^3 \rangle$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$.

I know this can easily be done via the formula $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{{\big(\frac{dx}{dt}}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dz}{dt}\big)^{2}}\,dt. $

I want to know if there is another method of computing the arc length without using this formula?

---

**EDIT**

**Using Neile's parabola**

Using: $\big(\frac{1}{27}\big) \times (4 + 9t^2)^{3/2} - \frac{8}{27}$ I got $\big(\frac{1}{27}\big) \times (4 + 9(1)^2)^{3/2} - \frac{8}{27}$. Plugging this into a calculator yields: $1.439$.

But when I used the first formula above, I got $3.605.$ Have I used the method wrong? Could you please explain?

Comment: In this special case, Neile's parabola, see https://books.google.de/books?id=JrslMKTgSZwC&pg=PA148&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false, it may be done differently.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: When I used the method given by you I got $1.439$ but when I used the formula I got $3.605$. Have I used the method wrong? Could you please explain.

Comment: It'll be helpful to post your calculations.

Comment: Adding it now...Done.

Comment: Using the integral you should get 1.439 as well.

Comment: @ryang No, I unaccepted it. It doesn't answer my question because it doesn't show a different way to computing the arc length of the vector function. If you edit your answer and turn it into a different method, I will accept that.

Comment: @Ajay Right, I see. It's fine; your own EDIT above had already self-answered your original question, so I was merely answering the other question—raised in your comment above—which was causing you confusion at that time.

Answer (score 2):

> I know this could easily be done via the formula $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{{\big(\frac{dx}{dt}}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dz}{dt}\big)^{2}}\,dt. $ When I use this formula I get $3.605$ instead of $1.439.$

\begin{align}
&\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{{\big(\frac{dx}{dt}}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)^{2} + \big(\frac{dz}{dt}\big)^{2}}\,dt
\\=&\int_0^1\sqrt{(2t)^2+0+(3t^2)^2}\,\mathrm dt
\\=&\int_0^1\sqrt{9t^4+4t^2}\,\mathrm dt
\end{align}
Substituting in $u=t^2:$
\begin{align}
=&\frac12\int_0^1\sqrt{9u+4}\,\mathrm du
\\=&\frac1{27}\left[(9u+4)^\frac32\right]_0^1
\\=&1.440,\end{align} as required.